# Support function of the intersection of a hyper-ellipsoid and a Euclidean ball

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, st.statistics, convex-geometry, convex-analysis, geometric-probability

Le $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_d$ be positive numbers. For any $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $r \ge 0$, define $\gamma(x,r) := \sup_{z \in E(r)}x^\top z$, where
$$
E(r) := E \cap B_2^d(r) = \{z \in \mathbb R^d \mid \sum_j z_j^2/\lambda_j \le 1,\, \|z\|_2 \le r\},
$$
the intersection of a hyper-ellipsoid $E := \{z \in \mathbb R^d \mid \sum_j z_j^2/\lambda_j \le 1\}$ and the Euclidean ball $B_2^d(r)$ of radius $r$. Note that for any $r \ne 0$, the mapping $x \mapsto \gamma(x,r)$ defines a norm on $\mathbb R^d$. Finally, from a statistical perspective, note that if $x \sim N(0,I_d)$, then $\mathbb E \gamma(x,r)$ is the Gaussian width of $E(r)$.

Also define $D(r) := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid \sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2/\lambda_j(r) \le 1\}$, where $\lambda_j(r) := \min(\lambda_j,r^2)$. Let $x \mapsto \omega(x,r)$ be the support function of $D(r)$.

**Question.** Are there absolute positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that
$$
\gamma(x,r) \le c_2\omega(x,c_1 r),
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $r \ge 0$.

Note that the reverse inequality holds. Indeed, if $x \in D(r)$, then $\sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2/\min(\lambda_j,r^2) \le 1$ and so

- $\sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2/\lambda_j \le 1$, i.e $x \in E$, and
- $\sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2/r^2 \le 1$, i.e $x \in B_2^d(r)$,

i.e, $x \in E(r)$. Thus, $D(r) \subseteq E(r)$, and we conclude that $\gamma \ge \omega$.

### Edit: Solution

We show that the claimed bound holds with $c_1=1$ and $c_2=\sqrt 2$. For this, it suffices to show that $E(r) \subset \sqrt{2} D(r)$. Indeed, let $x \in E(r)$. Then,
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_j x_j^2/\lambda_j(r) &= \sum_j x_j^2/\min(r^2,\lambda_j) = \sum_j x_j^2 \max(1/r^2,1/\lambda_j)\\
& \le \sum_j x_j^2 (1/r^2 + 1/\lambda_j) = \sum_j x_j^2/r^2 + \sum_j x_j^2/\lambda_j \le 1 + 1 = 2.
\end{split}
$$
Thus, $x \in \sqrt{2} D(r)$.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but it turns our the problem is solved by an argument of Theorem 2.1 of this paper https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume4/mendelson03a/mendelson03a.pdf. I'll close the question if nobody objects to it.

Comment: (i) Your inequality cannot be true, as it is not homogeneous in $x$. There seem to be three mistakes in the definition of $\omega$. (ii) Theorem 2.1 in the paper linked in your comment seems rather different from whatever you wanted to ask here. In particular, it involves random variables, in contrast with your post.

Comment: I omitted a square root sign in the definition of $\omega$. Fixed.

Comment: Concerning your, other comments, it is indeed shown in the reference that $D(r) \subseteq \mathcal E(r) \subseteq \sqrt{2} D(r)$, where $D(r) := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid \sum_j x_j^2/\lambda_j(r) \le 1\}$. There is no randomness involved here. The claim then follows upon comparing the support functions of these sets . No ?

Comment: Two more mistakes remaining there (try replacing $\lambda_j$ and $r^2$ by $t^2\lambda_j$ and $t^2r^2$).

Comment: Indeed, there are a couple of typographical mistakes. Editing. Thanks.

Comment: Also, your desired conclusion seems to be just stated, without proof, in the paper linked in your comment -- even though the proof is simple.

Comment: Hum, yes I think I see how to get the proof, by simply observing that $1/\min(a,b) = \max(1/a,1/b)  \le 1/a + 1/b$. This would give the $\sqrt 2$ factor.

Comment: Yes, the proof is very simple.

Comment: I've corrected the bugs in the statement of the question and posted a complete solution in an edit. The bugs where due to the fact that what I defined as $\omega$ was meant to be the dual norm of $\omega$ (i.e the support function of its unit ball). Thanks for the input